# What is the word to describe companies that are in the same industry?

Tags: nouns

I need to use only one word to describe companies that are of the same industry. "Competitors" is not right under this context. Is there a noun that means "of the same industry" or "in the same business"? Thanks!!

Comment: "Co-conspirators" often fits.

Comment: You could call them *peers*.

Comment: Sector, Apple, Microsoft & Oracle are all in the same sector

Comment: @HotLicks - That word applies only in a context where you are making an accusation on a bunch of entities for conspiring something. Generally, *sector* is used more often.

Answer (score 1):

[Player](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/player) is often used to denote a competitor without the 'competing' connotation:

> - a participant, esp a powerful one, in a particular field of activity.

- All active players in the financial industry.

Comment: Ah right, "player" does sound good. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Sector** is the most common and used in finance and stock talk. Examples:

`The IT sector is booming. 
The Auto sector is heading south.`

Another common way is to refer by the name of the industry itself. Examples:

`Banks are steady.
Technology had a field day today after Samsung announced their results.
Pharma looks good.
Biotech has shining prospects.`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the word "Affiliates":  We can partner with industry affiliates....